# How to create three overlapping layers without using "position" and "margins"

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I've gotten myself into trouble. This ms my markup:

```
<div class="header_wrap">
    <div class="header_row0"><img src="header-940x60.gif"></div>
    <table class="header_row1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/">Home</a></td>
                <td><a id="menuTrigger" href="#">More</a>
                    <ul id="menuContent" class="easymenu">
                        <li><a href="/link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/link2.html">Link 2</a></li>
                    </ul></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="header_row2">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/link3.html">Link 3</a></td>
                <td><a href="/link3.html">Link 4</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

To summarize, there are three items inside header_wrap:

1. header_row0
2. header_row1
3. header_row2

My objective is to position the header-940x60.gif image such that it appears as a background behind `header_row1` and `header_row2`. But here is what I CANNOT do:

1. I cannot place the header.gif in the background. The image's height may vary and I therefore must use header.gif inside an `<img>` tag without specifying dimensions. Besides I'll need alt tags for SEO sometime in the future.
2. I cannot use `position: relative` and `position: absolute` because the `#menuContent` is `position: absolute`. It needs to be positioned w.r.t. the page, using relative positioning on any of its container just srcews every thing up.
3. The height of the image is not known so I cannot use negative margins.

Please advice best way to achieve the following result without relative positioning:

[image: screenshot 1]

PS: In the screenshot you'll notice the the popup menu is not aligned with the left side of its trigger. This is the main problem.

This [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Nbb5q/) contains a skinned down version of the markup.

Comment: Why, oh why, are you using a table for layout?

Comment: Phasing out the tables is in the _todo_ list (its been there for the past 15 months :p)

Comment: You have a link to some of the code or can you post more substantial code with style info?   As Kyle & Salman pointed out your tables need to go (and they are the root of your problem) ...  More code and we can give you a better method and solution

Comment: Make a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) example, and I'll take a look.

Comment: JSBin seems to be screwed up. I've added jsFiddle link in the question.

Comment: I've been able to achieve this using 3 css rules, each about 2 lines. Consider this question closed :)

Comment: "Phasing out the tables is in the todo list (its been there for the past 15 months :p)" Tables haven't been acceptable for layout for a lot longer than 15 months ago. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used floats to achieve the overlapping effect. The first div was floated and then `width: 0` so that it does not occupy any space but still show the content (add `overflow: visible` if necessary). Since the div does not occupy any space the two tables (or divs if you choose) will appear over the image. A clearing div makes sure all remaining content appears *below* the background image div.

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nbb5q/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done without invoking either position:absolute to take the element out of flow and deal with it directly or using negative margins to artifically push the content around within flow. pos:abs is the correct solution (well a background image is in fact the correct solution but you'd have to have a fixed size) and your only chance here is to use it and repair the consequences.

This especially cannot be done with table elements which would take so much breaking as to become unreliable - it may be on your todo list to remove tables, but if you have a specific problem you need to fix the specific instance *now*.

Comment: Everyone please just assume that I have three divs instead of one div and two tables. Or just assume its just two divs, one containing the image, other containing two, one, or any number of divs.